# Trying to make a page in a Confluence Space using REST API

Tags: jira-rest-api, confluence

I am trying to do a post request on my companies confluence to make a page using the REST API.
When I attempt to do it, I get a JSON response saying that it is forbidden.
I am able to make a page from the GUI, but not with the REST Api.
I have done Basic Authentication for the query.
Here is a picture of the request and the response.

**My Question :** how can I make the page on the confluence space with the rest Api?

**I have tried:** making a personal access token. And then using it with my request, but that didn't work either.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The request body to create the page is a little different:

1. You should not use space as a container (only pages for comments as containers or attachments)
2. Do not use space id, just KEY
3. `storage` object should have a `representation` field and use its ID.

Here is the example:

```json
{
   "type":"page",
   "title":"TEST SEITE 2",
   "space":{
      "key":"MY_SPACE_KEY"
   },
   "body":{
      "storage":{
         "value":"<p>This is my storage</p>",
         "representation":"storage"
      }
   }
}
```